# Instantiation of templated function fails to resolve another function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, overload-resolution

In the following code, `foo<T>` and `bar<T>` call functions `operator+` and `someOtherFunction` that are defined *after* the templated functions, but *before* they are instantiated in `main()`.

Using clang, this works fine, **except for `bar<int>`**. Why isn't this allowed? `someOtherFunction(int)` is visible at the point of instantiation, which seems to be sufficient for both `foo<S>` and `bar<S>`.

```
template<typename T> void foo(T t) { (void)(t + t); }
template<typename T> void bar(T t) { someOtherFunction(t); }


struct S {};

// operator+(int, int) is built in
void operator+(const S& lhs, const S& rhs) {}

void someOtherFunction(int s) {}
void someOtherFunction(const S& s) {}

int main() {
    foo(42);  // works
    foo(S()); // works

    bar(42);  // error: call to function 'someOtherFunction' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
    bar(S()); // works
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> error: call to function 'someOtherFunction' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
>     someOtherFunction(t);
>     ^
> note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'bar<int>' requested here
>     bar(42);
>     ^
> note: 'someOtherFunction' should be declared prior to the call site
> void someOtherFunction(int s) {}
>      ^
> ```

Comment: I think this may be due to some confluence of concepts related to two-phase lookup, the global namespace, and the type-based differences in ADL sets defined in **[basic.lookup.argdep]**, esp: "_If T is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespaces and classes are both empty_" and that that `S` as an argument type pulls in the global namespace in which it's declared. But, I don't understand this well enough to form a complete picture (or am way off...).

Comment: @mkal That's spot on. ADL does not apply in the case of fundamental types.

Comment: someOtherFunction() has to be defined or forward declared, before the first usage. This at least solves the problem, but i'm not sure if it also solves your question, since i can't explain, why it has to.